# Chrome Dev Tools Cannot Expand Iframe contents

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

As seen in the picture above, this iframe contains an html file but now its contents cannot be expanded. Before Chrome 56 I have been able to expand the contents, now I cannot. Is there something else I must provide for it to expand now?

This iframe is being used here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loom-video-recorder-scree/liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb

in the camera bubble view

Comment: What extension does the ID in the iframe src correspond to? I can't find it in the Chrome App Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps anyone but I had the same problem. It turns out if you just scroll down the Elements window you'll see the frame right at the bottom, took me a while to figure that out.

`Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: unfortunately right-click -> inspect doesn't scroll down automatically to the corresponding element. very annoying to have to go through all the markup manually :/

Answer (score 4):

Chrome now runs iframes in separate chrome renderer processes to optimize performance.

To view such an [OOPIF](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes):

- METHOD 1. Right-click the iframe contents on the page, then `Inspect` to invoke a separate devtools window.
- METHOD 2. The upcoming devtools UI (see [crbug.com/652783](https://crbug.com/652783#c8)) lists such iframes in the same devtools under the main page DOM in Elements inspector:

  > This work is in progress and available behind an experimental feature in DevTools.
  >
  > 1. Enable "Developer Tools experiments" on chrome://flags, and restart.
  > 2. Open DevTools Settings, go to Experiments tab, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> 7 times.
  > 3. Check "Auto-attach to cross-process subframes."

  Note, on Windows you may see a sticky keys dialog on the 5th tap, just close it and continue.

Test site with an iframe: http://csreis.github.io/tests/cross-site-iframe-simple.html

[image: pic]

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. One questions though. Should this be happening when the flag is disabled? http://i.imgur.com/Seb8DjD.png

Comment: Yes, the flags become obsolete which happens regularly when a feature is [almost] implemented. In such cases it's enabled for everyone or a subset of users via FieldTrials or content features mechanisms that can be still controlled (until the feature is considered 100% stable) by running chrome with --disable-features or --disable-blink-features or --force-fieldtrials command line parameters.

Comment: I can confirm that this feature is no longer experimental, and instead, has been moved to be the default feature in the Elements tab. (Nov 10, 2017)